# Postgres via Airflow not returning query result - frozen until timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, psycopg2

I'm using airflow 2.2.0 on docker and issuing several queries through an ETL pipeline. Everything is working fine until I reach a particular query which looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO final_table (
    col1,
    col2
)
SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM some_temp_table
LEFT JOIN some_other_tables
```

This query should take around 30 seconds to complete on the larger set of tables I've got. However, what happens is that the query is issued by Airflow to Postgres and then nothing gets returned for around 5 minutes until Airflow eventually crashes the pipeline due to not receiving any response in that particular task I believe.

The error is the following:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
    (...)
    self._execute_queries(connection=connection, cursor=cursor, query=query)
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

I've checked everything I could think of and can't detect anything weird. The `pg_stat_activity` table shows the query is always in active state and doesn't seem to be getting blocked by any other query.

The logs of Postgres show that the query issued by Airflow is received by Postgres. Logs as follows:

```
[3244] LOG:  statement: BEGIN
[3244] LOG:  statement: 

INSERT INTO final_table (
    col1,
    col2
)
SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM some_temp_table
LEFT JOIN some_other_tables
```

But after that, no COMMIT command is issued by postgres (as it happens for all other transactions). The query just seems to hang on that state indefinitely.

When I run this same exact query directly via the database client (DBeaver in this case), everything works fine and the query gets run and the table filled in 30 seconds. Also when I run the same ETL pipeline but with a smaller dataset, everything works well and the query gets run successfully via Airflow.

I'm really confused as to what the problem may be and where to focus my attention on. If anyone has gone through something similar, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PostgresOperator or PostgresHook?

Have you enabled the autocommit flag?

Take a look at this example and see if it helps.

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator

# create_pet_table, populate_pet_table, get_all_pets, and get_birth_date are examples of tasks created by
# instantiating the Postgres Operator

with DAG(
    dag_id="postgres_operator_dag",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    # [START postgres_operator_howto_guide_create_pet_table]
    create_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_pet_table",
        sql="""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (
            pet_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            pet_type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
            OWNER VARCHAR NOT NULL);
          """,
    )
    # [END postgres_operator_howto_guide_create_pet_table]
    # [START postgres_operator_howto_guide_populate_pet_table]
    populate_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="populate_pet_table",
        sql="""
            INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER)
            VALUES ( 'Max', 'Dog', '2018-07-05', 'Jane');
            INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER)
            VALUES ( 'Susie', 'Cat', '2019-05-01', 'Phil');
            INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER)
            VALUES ( 'Lester', 'Hamster', '2020-06-23', 'Lily');
            INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER)
            VALUES ( 'Quincy', 'Parrot', '2013-08-11', 'Anne');
            """,
    )
    # [END postgres_operator_howto_guide_populate_pet_table]
    # [START postgres_operator_howto_guide_get_all_pets]
    get_all_pets = PostgresOperator(task_id="get_all_pets", sql="SELECT * FROM pet;")
    # [END postgres_operator_howto_guide_get_all_pets]
    # [START postgres_operator_howto_guide_get_birth_date]
    get_birth_date = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="get_birth_date",
        sql="""
            SELECT * FROM pet
            WHERE birth_date
            BETWEEN SYMMETRIC DATE '{{ params.begin_date }}' AND DATE '{{ params.end_date }}';
            """,
        params={'begin_date': '2020-01-01', 'end_date': '2020-12-31'},
    )
    # [START postgres_operator_howto_guide_get_birth_date]

    create_pet_table >> populate_pet_table >> get_all_pets >> get_birth_date
    # [END postgres_operator_howto_guide]
```

Tutorial: https://registry.astronomer.io/dags/example-postgres

Comment: I'm actually using the PostgresHook and issue the queries in Python using psycopg2. The query get's issued from Airflow to Postgres (as detailed in the Postgres logs - there's the log of the query arriving to be processed) but somewhere after that it seems like it never gets executed or returned. Hence why I'm thinking the problem may actually be in Postgres rather than Airflow.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you instantiate the hook and execute the query?